# Regex to match any chinese character in R

Tags: r, regex

What is the regex to match any Chinese character in R?

`[\\p{Han}]` doesn't seem to work as expected.

```
v=c("a","b","c","中","e","文")
grep("[\\p{Han}]",v, value = TRUE)

[1] "a"
```

Comment: Try this rudimentary option: `Filter(function(x) Encoding(x)=="UTF-8", v)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#script), *"The JGsoft engine, **Perl**, PCRE, PHP, Ruby 1.9, Delphi, and XRegExp can match Unicode scripts"*. So setting `perl = T` should produce the correct results. The R default is a modified version of Ville Laurikari's TRE engine ([source](https://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html)):

```r
grep("[\\p{Han}]", v, value = T, perl = T)

#### OUTPUT ####

[1] "中" "文"
```